# Using flat table in MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq

If I have a model that has several tables, and I am joining these tables together into a flat table within my controller class, how do I get the view to be able to access the flat table?

For example, let's say I have three tables in my model (customers, orders, invoices).
Orders are linked to customer by a foreign key (CustomerID), and invoices are linked to orders by a foreign key (OrderID).

In order to see all of this in one flat table (with all customers listed, even if they don't have orders, and all orders listed, even if they don't have invoices), I have the following anonymous type:

```
var FlatTable = (from a in customers
let CustomerID = a.ID
join b in orders on a.ID equals b.CustomerID into ab
from b in ab.DefaultIfEmpty()
let OrderID = b.ID
join c in invoices on b.ID equals c.InvoiceID into ac
from c in ac.DefaultIfEmpty()
let InvoiceID = c.ID
select new {a.CustomerName, CustomerID, OrderID, b.ProductDescription, InvoiceID, c.InvoiceAmount});

return View(FlatTable.ToList());
```

Then in my View (which is based on my model), how am I able to access FlatTable.

Comment: I think I figured it out.  I had to create a generic ViewModel class and then cast my anonymous type to an IEnumerable of my ViewModel class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
IList<ViewModel> model = (from a in customers
join b in orders on a.ID equals b.CustomerID into ab
from b in ab.DefaultIfEmpty()
join c in invoices on b.ID equals c.InvoiceID into ac
from c in ac.DefaultIfEmpty()
select new ViewModel() {CustomerName = a.CustomerName, CustomerID = a.ID, OrderID = b.ID, ProductDescription = b.ProductDescription, InvoiceID = c.ID, InvoiceMaount = c.InvoiceAmount}).ToList();
```